# Python Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open this file in text mode?)

Tags: python, import-from-csv

I am having difficulty alleviating the following error in a Python script I am working on:

```
line 37, in <module>
for u in ur:_csvError: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

The corresponding code (lines 33-41):

```
with open(file_all_traffic,'rb') as url:
    ur=csv.reader(url)
    to_find=[]
    all_traffic=[]
    for u in ur:
        to_find.append(u[0])
        all_traffic.append(u[1])

l=len(to_find)
```

All of the files I've tried importing were CSVs, yet I continue to get this error.

Removing the binary from 'rb' seems to cause a problem with blank spaces, so I believe that it is supposed to stay (this is an existing script that used to work, just repairing it :) ).

Any ideas as to why this is reading my csv files as text?

Comment: Can you format your code please so it's easily readable. Indent each line by 4 spaces to do so.

Comment: I suspect that this is Python 2 code and you are trying to run it on Python 3.

Comment: The Python 2 csv module requires binary mode files, but the  Python 3 csv module requires text mode files. Please see the docs for further details.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for editing, I was having difficulty getting the formatting of the code correct- Would you mind sharing a link to the doc you mention? Thanks! 
Thank you, I will look into it and check back shortly :)

Comment: I tried changing the rb to rt per: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html and am still not seeing any difference when I run it


"# Python 2 and 3:
f = open(pathname)

# But preferably, use this:
from io import open
f = open(pathname, 'rb')   # if f.read() should return bytes
# or
f = open(pathname, 'rt')   # if f.read() should return unicode text"

Comment: could you show the "problem with blank spaces"? The error clearly says "should return strings, not bytes" so it definitely needs to be in text mode not bytes. (Probably need to specify an encoding?)